# laravel localhost base_url 500

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

I've had an app built for me using laravel and I'm trying to get it running on my local machine (MacBook pro running MAMP).

The lead developer is currently away so i was hoping someone could help me with my problem!

No matter what I do, I only get a white page when trying to run the app from a browser, even though I believe I've set the config and htaccess file correctly.

Mamp is running on port 8888 and the app is in the 'event' directory. The config file has the base url as:

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/event/';

but all I get is a white page. I have checked php and thats running fine, and if I call other files outside of the laravel app they all work.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can diagnose the issue using the developer bar or some other tool? At the moment all I can see is a 500 error.

Thanks!

Comment: Check you storage/logs/laravel.log and/or apache error log file.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I have tried adding that but no luck. I doubted it would work thought because the head or body is not even loaded. The html of the rendered site simply reads:

<html><head></head><body></body></html>

As for the log file, the only .log file i could find was app.log which had nothing too recent in it.

Comment: open up `public/index.php` and write `exit('test')` at the very top right after opening `<?php`-tag. See if your app even gets there, which it most likely won't – so the problem is in MAMP settings

Comment: Yes, that works. (just renders 'test')

Comment: @AniketSahrawat why are you suggesting that if you are not Laravel user? In Laravel, we have `laravel.log` which will log this for us, there's no need to do what you wrote, nor is there  "header" to add it to. Web server's log will also log any fatal errors. It looks like you're missing some sort of a service, maybe the database, so it errors out after failing to speak to that service. Look for your web server logs, read them, the error is there.

Comment: I know laravel logs it. I thought it would be nicer if you get the problem to display on the same page. By header I mean top of the page...offcourse I am not much familiar with laravel but that should work just fine fo displaying run time errors. @N.B.

Comment: If it's not displayed, it means your developer disabled it. It's a common practice to hide errors from people who are using the site and displaying something else. Since he hasn't told you how to make it work locally, you can't assume things out of the blue. I suggest you ask that guy to set it up for you, after all - you hired him for that. Unless you can give us all the details here, no one can help you the way you expect it. Good luck with your site.

Comment: If it's not displayed, it means your developer disabled it. It's a common practice to hide errors from people who are using the site and displaying something else. Since he hasn't told you how to make it work locally, you can't assume things out of the blue. I suggest you ask that guy to set it up for you, after all - you hired him for that. Unless you can give us all the details here, no one can help you the way you expect it. Good luck with your site.

Comment: If it's not displayed, it means your developer disabled it. It's a common practice to hide errors from people who are using the site and displaying something else. Since he hasn't told you how to make it work locally, you can't assume things out of the blue. I suggest you ask that guy to set it up for you, after all - you hired him for that. Unless you can give us all the details here, no one can help you the way you expect it. Good luck with your site.